# How do I remove all the letters from a CSV file?

Tags: python

How would I go about removing letters and numbers except 1s and 0s from my CSV file. I have tried using Pandas but I do not think that I used it correctly to accomplish the task.

Comment: If on a Unix(-like) system, or if you have access to GNU tools, `sed` would be a perfect fit for the job.

Comment: `"".join(x for x in text if x in "01")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already loaded this file into a matrix (stored in variable `csv` here):

```py
for x in range(len(csv)):
    for y in range(len(csv[x])):
        if csv[x][y] not in ["1", "0"]:
            csv[x][y] = ""
```

This code will change all characters, that are not 1s or 0s to empty strings. If necessary, you can easily modify this code to change them to any other value, or completely remove them from the matrix (however, in this case, `while` loops are necessary).